# gulp build with tfs readonly files (angular-seed)

Tags: angular, tfs, gulp, angular-seed

i'm using mgechev's excellent angular-seed, but my company uses TFS. When I build I get EPERM errors due to read only files in the /dist folder.

I've installed --save-dev gulp-chmod and tried to add it in the pipe to remove read only flag (note: working in windows) but when I run the task it says "cannot find module 'gulp-chmod'"

do I need to register or map gulp-chmod somewhere else first?

Answer (score 0):

TFS makes the files readonly. 
The problem is when gulp copy them with readonly attribute.

You can do in other way, create task and use `child_process`, 
like this (run this after each sequence):

```
import {join} from 'path';
import {APP_SRC, APP_DEST} from '../config';

var exec = require('child_process').exec;

export = function vsCleanReadonly(done) {
    return function (done) {
        var cmd = 'attrib -r ' + APP_DEST + '/*.* /s';
        exec(cmd, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
            done();
        });
    }
}
```